# On combining two different approximations of a function for two different limits together

Tags: functions, approximation, curves

I have an infinite sum (a function of $x$, say $f(x)$) which I can approximate by two different functions, say by $f_1(x)$ and by $f_2(x)$ for small and large values of $x$, respectively.

Is there a way to combine $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ together which could be a reasonably good approximation of $f(x)$ for the whole domain?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are we talking about a function series ? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @nicomezi: It seems clear enough to me. A function of $x$ is to be approximated. It happens to be given by an infinite sum, but that doesn't really matter much for the question how best to combine two approximations.

Comment: My sentence "Your question is not clear" was also referring to the fact that "a good approximation" can dépends a lot on the context. @joriki

Comment: Please see my previous answer to a similar problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467128/asymptotic-behaviour-and-curve-guessing/2468242#2468242

Answer (score 0):

There are many such ways; I'll suggest one but you may have to adapt it for your particular setting.

I take it that you have good approximations for $x\to0$ and for $x\to\infty$; for instance, asymptotic approximations such that

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_1(x)}{f(x)}=1\;,\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f_2(x)}{f(x)}=1\;.
$$

Since we're dealing with scales here, I'd suggest using the logarithm of $x$ as a parameter. If you mix your functions like this:

$$
f_{12}(x)=w(x)f_1(x) + (1-w(x))f_2(x)\;,
$$

you could choose the weight function $w(x)$ to be a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) in $\ln x$:

$$
w(x)=\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{k(\ln x-\ln x_0)}}\;,
$$

where $x_0$ is the midpoint of the transition and $k$ is a free parameter that controls the steepness of the transition (the limit $k\to\infty$ corresponds to an abrupt jump from $f_1$ to $f_2$ at $x_0$, and the smaller $k$, the smoother the transition). This can be rewritten as

$$
w(x)=\frac1{1+\left(\frac x{x_0}\right)^k}\;.
$$

Let me know if you need help adapting this to your setting.